# Calculate NFC Tag size to store static data

Tags: rfid, nfc

I'm trying to design a system that transfers the DateTime of entry and exit of people to another system. The data is log of records per week for each person and must be transferred once. These data are stored on a device and I want to find some way to transfer it to the target system.

I'm thinking about using RFID or NFC Tags for each person. I'm not familiar with these technologies but I read that NFC can store 8KB of data but I'm not sure if I can fit each person's data into it or how much data I can save on them.

Suppose that a person would go in and out 50 times per day and for a week it would be a maximum of 350 records that each one is a timestamp plus in-out type (8+1 bytes) and thus it would be about 3KB of data per week. It sounds OK for me but I'm not sure about the cost of each card or which type should I choose.
Also, I'm not sure if my calculation is right or how the data structure of these tags is.

Comment: why store the information on the card/tag? Just read the id of the tag on entry/exit and store the information in a database linked to the reader that can be read later and can hold years worth of data.

Comment: You are right but I made a simple example for demonstration only. I should grab the logs in a tag or device to be able to transfer it to somewhere else.

Comment: Also you need to look at the write times for larger volumes of data on these devices, they are not quick to write "larger" volumes of data.

Comment: @hardillb Thanks for the tip. Actually I'm not familiar with this tech so I'm not sure about how the performance is. May I ask how much time it takes to write a large volume data like 4KB. I choose this way rather than using a portable flash drive, etc. for its simplicity and quickness.